# Passing an array from jQuery to PHP via JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I want to send an array from my client jQuery code to my server PHP code. 
On the jQuery side, this is what I am doing:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: someUrl,
    data: {
       action:  'opensearch',
       search:  query,
       namespace:   [10, 846],
       suggest:     ''
    },
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

On PHP's side:

```
echo $params['action'] ."\r\n";
echo $params['namespace'][0] ."\r\n";
echo $params['namespace'][1] ."\r\n";
```

The output of this is:

```
opensearch
0
```

So the parameters are sent correctly as I manage to print the string correctly. However the array appears not to sent correctly.

I have tried to use `json_decode` with and without the `true` option but to no avail.

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax( {
    url: someUrl,
    type:'post'
    data: encodeURIComponent('action=opensearch&search=query&namespace[]=10&namespace[]=846&suggest='),
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

php

```
$params=json_decode($_POST);
    echo $params->action;
```

Comment: For reference, the dataType option on $.ajax tells jQuery the response type to expect, not the request type to submit

Answer (score 1):

json_decode() converts valid JSON strings into objects. It accepts three parameters each
of which is described below:

The JSON string itself.

Optional parameter assoc: By default this value is false. If changed to true,
   json_decode will convert objects to associative arrays

Depth: Maximum allowed depth of a recursive structure in the JSON string. It used
   to be 128 before PHP 5.3. PHP 5.3 has this limit increased to 512 bytes default.
  This parameter is also optional.

```
$objJson = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is not being posted as JSON, it is being posted in a proper HTTP POST.

However, PHP will only convert it to an array of the name of the field is structured in such a way that indicates it is an array. Try replacing: `namespace: [10, 846]` with `"namespace[]": [10, 846]`

Right now, jQuery is likely posting this: `namespace=10&namespace=846`, which will not be properly converted to an array. Adding the square brackets should take care of that.

Comment: I hope you are removing any `json_decode` or anything you may have. I was actually incorrect in telling you to add square brackets, jQuery will do that for you - however, you do not need to do any processing on your server side. Just `var_dump($_POST)` and you will see the data you are looking for. I just tested this as well with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to decode your `$_POST` variable, actually, `$_POST` already contain your data as you want them.

Just have a test, create a jsonpost.php with the following code :

```
<?php

    if (count($_POST) > 0)
    {
        header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        echo nl2br(var_export($_POST, true));
        die();
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="target"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $.ajax( {
                url: 'jsonpost.php',
                type:'post',
                data: {
                   action:  'opensearch',
                   search:  'test',
                   namespace:   [10, 846],
                   suggest:     ''
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#target').html(data);
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will display :

```
array (
  'action' => 'opensearch',
  'search' => 'test',
  'namespace' =>
  array (
    0 => '10',
    1 => '846',
  ),
  'suggest' => '',
)
```

Your main mistake is that you're thinking that `dataType` will **POST** your data as json, but actually the `dataType` content will define the **EXPECTED** data to get (to have an already-decoded object when calling your callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

Try logging your received data and see what you have received, I have tested you ajax post using the following code, and it returns the value 10 as desired:

```
   $data = $_REQUEST;
   error_log($data['namespace'][0]."\n",3,"log.txt");
   print_r($data['namespace'][0]);
```

Also use, error and success options to see what response you are getting from your php script

```
   $.ajax( {
   url: 'rec.php',
   data: {
      action:  'opensearch',
      search:  "abc",
      namespace:   [10, 846],
      suggest:     ''
   },
   dataType: 'json',
   error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));

  },
  success: function (data) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
 }
 });
});
```

Comment: For complete data you can use, error_log(serialize($data)."\n",3,"log.txt");

Answer (score 0):

you are sending form data, so it's not going to be json_encoded.

```
$.ajax( {
    url: someUrl,
    data: {
        json_string: JSON.stringify({
            action:  'opensearch',
            search:  query,
            namespace:   [10, 846],
            suggest:     ''
        })
    },
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

and then on the PHP side

```
$data = json_decode($params['json_string'], true);
```